# How can I define comment syntax for a major mode?

Tags: emacs, comments, dot-emacs

I'd like to add comments to a major mode that I use that doesn't currently support them. The only examples I can find online show how to write [single-line comments](http://notfaq.wordpress.com/2006/09/30/emacs-simple-comment-syntax/), but I need paired delimiters.

What do I need to change?

Comment: Which command do you use to comment/uncomment?

Comment: `M-;`, which I believe is bound to `comment-region`.

Comment: Expanding on the example you linked to, you simply need to set the `comment-end` variable in addition to `comment-start`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up digging in to the elisp of the package that I was working with. The problem is that if you add

```
(setq comment-start "FOO")
(setq comment-end "BAR")
```

to `your-mode-hook`, then, when you switch to another language that defines `comment-start` but not `comment-end`, then you end up with `comment-end` sticking from the other mode. For example, your `python-mode` comments look like:

```
# def my_func(): BAR
```

which definitely isn't what you want. In order to fix that, use the following:

```
(add-hook 'your-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (set (make-local-variable 'comment-start) "FOO")
            (set (make-local-variable 'comment-end) "BAR")))
```

and it won't clobber other modes' `comment-end`.